# Camera always returns 0 in resultCode and with incorrect data in onActivityResult, but only on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, onactivityresult

I've the problem described in title.

If done with a physical device I own, resultCode is -1 and data is always correct.

But with emulator resultCode is always 0 and data, though not null, is incorrect, looks like a empty intent.

This looks like some issue from emulator rather than something on my code, guess I should contact emulator team from Android Studio.

Anyway maybe I'm missing something, I've done other projects in the past that requested photos, with older emulator and Android Studio versions and this problem never happened. So it's kind of puzzling that it does not work now.

Any idea of why the emulator could fail into retrieving the data and the resultCode?